# Caching an Array in ModX

Tags: php, arrays, caching, modx

I had the Problem that I had two snippets one must be called uncached and in this I needed to retrieve an array that is generated in another snippet that must be called cached.

Caching the array is not possible and I mustn't call the snippet more often than once a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to cache an array you can jsonencode it and store it in the cache manager like this:

`$modx->cacheManager->set('cache_name', json_encode($tldlist), 604800); // json encoding the array and caching it for 1 week`

Then when you needed the cached Array you can retrieve it and jsondecode it:

```
$tldarray = $modx->cacheManager->get('cache_name'); //retrieving the json string
$tldarray = json_decode($tldarray, 1); // and then converting it to an array
```

If the cache is expired you need to check if the array is NULL

```
$tldarray = $modx->cacheManager->get('cache_name');
$tldarray = json_decode($tldarray, 1);

if($tldarray == NULL){
$tldarray = $modx->runSnippet('tld_array'); //The snippet tld_array generates the array that I need
$tldarray = $modx->cacheManager->get('tld_array');
$tldarray = json_decode($tldarray, 1); //this converts the json string back to an array
}
```